# WebSphere MQ binary fiiles

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, binary, ibm-mq

This might be a question that may not be answered due to the nature of the external tool I am using (lack of documentation).

Basically, I am using a tool that pushes and pulls messages from the queue, more precisely - it pushes and pulls files. It worked perfectly for text files but when I tried pushing and then pulling a binary file - the pulled one was corrupted, it's size increased in comparsion with the original file (1.33 ratio).

For example moving a zip file wouldn't work...

I suppose it has something to do with the tools configuration, the only settings that can be changed regarding the problem are CCSID and encoding (UTF-8, Base16, etc.), I tried playing with both, unfortunately without success.

Tried using the following CCSIDs: 65535, 1208, 819
and encodings : UTF-8, Base16, Base64

In every case the binary file was corrupted after pulling it from the queue, I'm not entirely sure how the tool acomplishes that, it's written in Java, also I'm new to MQ so I tried searching for the correct options in IBM's docs but I haven't found anything that makes more sense than 65535 and Base16, yet it still doesn't work, could anyone with more experience with MQ tell if playing with these options makes sense at all in this case and if so - suggest what CCSID and encoding can I try to accomplish what Ive described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More information is really needed, but my suspicion is you are putting the message on the queue as a text message and playing around with encodings and ccsid's to try to get it right. You really need to know how the 'Java' app achieves this - is it using JMS (eg JMSBytesMessage) or base Java (something like setMessageData).

At a high level, there is a header on a message (The MD) which 'describes' the data - the MD format field. If you say the data is a string then MQ can convert between codepages should the getter request it etc. Put a tiny binary file into a message onto a queue, and browse the queue with amqsbcg or the GUI - what are the MD fields for format? What headers are on the payload - anything like RFH2's?

Put the same code in to give us a clue, or at least the amqsbcg output

Comment: Format : MQHRF2, CCSID : 1208, Encofing: 273. I think thats all the interesting infomation I was able to retrieve from the GUI

Comment: Look in the RFH2 header - what is the format in there?

Comment: This has been resolved, the tool was designed to push only certain types of files and it converted the binary data to string :(, thanks for the help.